# Is it possible to use variables in node red nodes (e.g. post requests)?

Tags: node-red

I have a flow which returns a variable outMsg from a function which then sends an HTTPS POST request from a request node, what I'm wondering is if I can use that variable in the request node after the function something like:

https://url.com?message={{outMsg}}

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the sidebar doc for the http-request node

> When configured within the node, the URL property can contain mustache-style tags. These allow the url to be constructed using values of the incoming message. For example, if the url is set to example.com/{{topic}}, it will have the value of msg.topic automatically inserted.